# Array gives no output outside Function in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, administrator

Here is the code

```
$conn =  'saruspc01', '194.195.5.65'

 function lll {
    foreach($co in $conn)
    {
       $check = Test-Connection $co -Count 3 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
       $zugriffzeit = $check | select ResponseTime | Measure-Object ResponseTime -Average
       $avg = [system.math]::Round($zugriffzeit.Average)

        if($check -eq $null)
        {
            $pcre = Write-Output $co
            $pire = Write-Output 'False'
            $zure = 'Null'
        }
        else
        {
            $pcre = Write-Output $co
            $pire = Write-Output 'True'
            $zure = Write-Output "$avg ms"
            $zure = $zure.Replace(' ','')
        }
        $table += @( @{PCName=$pcre;    PingResult=$pire;    Zugriffszeit=$zure} )
        #$table | ForEach {[PSCustomObject]$_} | Format-Table -AutoSize
    }
}
```

If I execute the same code without Function, it works. I need the Funktion though and want to do this is this way. How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you expect from the function? How do you want to invoke it and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big issue is that you're adding items to `$table` but you don't `return` the table output back to the user.  So, first things first, modify the end of your function to read like this.  (I added the comment `#EndOfForEach` to help highlight where the changes need to go.

```
        $table += @( @{PCName=$pcre;    PingResult=$pire;    Zugriffszeit=$zure} )                
    }#EndOfForEach
    return $table
}
```

With that change done, your function will work but only when you call it like so:

```
PS:\>lll
Name                           Value                                             
----                           -----                                             
PCName                         behemoth                                          
Zugriffszeit                   1ms                                               
PingResult                     True                                              
PCName                         notonline                                         
Zugriffszeit                   Null                                              
PingResult                     False
```

At this point, I'd recommend two changes.  One, the layout is hard to read, so I'd convert the function to use a `[psCustomObject]` datatype instead, like so.

```
function lll {
    $results = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    #...

   $results.Add([psCustomObject]@{PCName=$pcre;    PingResult=$pire;    Zugriffszeit=$zure})| Out-Null
    }#EndOfForEach
    return $results
}
```

For an output like so:

```
PS>lll

PCName    PingResult Zugriffszeit
------    ---------- ------------
behemoth  True       1ms         
notonline False      Null
```

And if you want to take your function to the next level, you'd be well serverd to look to modify the function to accept parameters instead of relying on the `$conn` variable already being set.  Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions or if I could dig deeper into an area.

#### Why doesn't `$results` maintain a value?

PowerShell uses variable scoping, so the `$results` variable we define in this function will only exist **for as long as the function is running**.  To keep the results, assign them to a variable when you call the function, like this.

```
$MyPingResults = lll
#no output is written to screen.

PS>$MyPingResults #get all results
PCName    PingResult Zugriffszeit
------    ---------- ------------
behemoth  True       1ms         
notonline False      Null     

PS>$myPingResults[0] #get first result

PCName   PingResult Zugriffszeit
------   ---------- ------------
behemoth True       7ms         

PS>$myPingResults | Where PingResult -eq $false #only get failed results

PCName    PingResult Zugriffszeit
------    ---------- ------------
notonline False      Null
```

#### Completed Script

```
function lll {
    $results = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    foreach($co in $conn)
    {
       $check = Test-Connection $co -Count 3 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
       $zugriffzeit = $check | select ResponseTime | Measure-Object ResponseTime -Average
       $avg = [system.math]::Round($zugriffzeit.Average)

        if($check -eq $null)
        {
            $pcre = Write-Output $co
            $pire = Write-Output 'False'
            $zure = 'Null'
        }
        else
        {
            $pcre = Write-Output $co
            $pire = Write-Output 'True'
            $zure = Write-Output "$avg ms"
            $zure = $zure.Replace(' ','')
        }
        $results.Add([psCustomObject]@{PCName=$pcre;    PingResult=$pire;    Zugriffszeit=$zure})| Out-Null
    }#EndOfForEach
    return $results
}
```

Comment: After the changes were applied, it showed the result, when I executed the script. Then I tried to invoke the table array, in which I saved the output, but the table array seems to be empty. only when executing the script it shows the output, otherwise, it is empty

Comment: I'll post the full and complete script, I think you may have missed a change.

Comment: Ah, I see your problem, I'll edit that into my answer

Comment: Happy it helps, make sure to mark as answer and upvote if it was useful :)

Comment: one last question. How can I eliminate this unwanted numbers of array position:              PS C:\Users\Lokal-keeran> $sd = lll   #put the function lll into the variable $sd                                                                                               

PS C:\Users\Lokal-keeran> $sd
0 #wanto to eliminate this
1
                                                       
PCName       PingResult Zugriffszeit
------       ---------- ------------
keeranpc01   True       3ms         
192.168.0.65 False      Null

Comment: On the line beginning with `$results.Add(...`, prepend this to the front. `[void]`.  When you call a `.Add()` method in dotnet you will generally get back the *index* or the numeric position in the array where your new record is stored.  If you don't want it, then casting it to the void will suppress that output.

Comment: how can I add a continuous loop to this function, which could be stopped by pressing the space key? Sorry for disturbing man. I am learning PowerShell so it would be great if you could help me.